# "Legacies in a field of study"?

Tags: phrase-usage

I want to speak of "his legacies in a field of study", but I am wondering if such usage is correct?

I have googled about the usage and found that seemingly no such usage exists. If this is the case, then what is the correct way to express "his legacies in a field of study"?

Answer (score 2):

His (great, extraordinary) contributions in his field of study are his legacy.
His legacy is his contributions to his field of study.
His legacies in his fields of study are numerous.
He left many legacies to various charities.

Usually one person leaves behind a legacy, not legacies.  That is why your search for "legacies" found very few results.

Comment: +1 I would add that we ordinarily speak of legacies *to* the beneficiaries, even when the beneficiary is a field of study: *Tolkien's legacy to Old English studies*, *Ranke's legacy to historiography*.